# Python webscraper outputs brackets with the number

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, stockquotes

I'm running python 3.3 on windows. The code below goes to yahoo finance and pulls the stock price and prints it. The problem I'm running into is that it outputs:

> > ['540.04']

I just want the number so I can turn it into a float and use it with formulas. I tried just using the float function, but that didn't work. I think I have to somehow remove the brackets and apostrophes with some line of code.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    htmlfile = urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&q1=1")

    Thefind = re.compile ('<span id="yfs_l84_aapl">(.+?)</span>')

    msg=htmlfile.read()

    price = Thefind.findall(str(msg))

    print (price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *beautiful* thing about BeautifulSoup is that you *don't* have to use regexp to parse HTML data.

This is the correct way of using BS:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&q1=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
my_span = soup.find('span', {'id': 'yfs_l84_aapl'})
print(my_span.text)
```

Which yields

```
540.04
```

Comment: I ended with the output: None , Something got messed up. I used     print (my_span) because it didn't recognize my_span.text.

Comment: I got this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string' I did a google search and it seems it has something to do with the output>> None

Comment: I found out the true problem was that when I wrote l84, I used a one instead of a lowercase "L". They look so a like in Idle. I feel bad now. I tried string as well. They both work perfectly. Thank you for the assistance. I'll be looking into Beautiful Soup's capabilities.

Comment: That's good! :) I've tried parsing HTML with regexp before, and believe me - you wont regret using BS instead! It's like heaven compared to hell

Answer (score 0):

The function findall() returns a list. If you just want the first group, pick it like this:

```
Thefind.findall(msg)[0]
```

But referring to any group is done cleaner like this:

```
Thefind.match(msg).group(1)
```

Note: `group(0)` is the whole match, not the first group.

Comment: doc sys it's a list and not an array.  re.findall(pattern, string[, flags])
    Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

Answer (score -1):

Use Python built-in functions
`float(price.strip("[']"))`

Comment: It didn't work out, because the number is in a list, but I learned a new function.